# end java program when input 'q'

Tags: java, input, terminate

i want to end my java program if i input q or Q. 
otherwise, the program will continue running, printing the question and asking for input.
will this work?

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
while(sc.hasNext())
{
System.out.print("Enter departure city <'Q' or 'q' to exit>: ");
String input = sc.next();

if(!(input.equals('q')) || !(input.equals('Q'))){
//system continues
}
else{
System.exit(0);
}
}
```

Comment: Have you tried? What error did you get?

Answer (score 1):

```
String input = "";

while (!input.toUpperCase().equals("Q"))
{
   System.out.print("Enter departure city. <'Q' or 'q' to exit>: ");
   input = sc.next();
}
```

Exit after the while loop.

Comment: Use equalsIgnoreCase instead of converting to uppercase and then checking equality. Its best practice due to locale issues.

Comment: Good point. `while( !input.equalsIgnoreCase("q") )`  is a bit more readable.